# errno vs errors returned by library functions

Tags: c, libraries, error-handling

For `errno`, there are a bunch of library functions, like `strerror()`, etc. to convert or print the error code.

But what about the error codes returned by library functions?

E.g. `write()` will return `EAGAIN`, `EBADF`, etc.

**Where do these symbols come from? Are they compatible with `strerror()` &co?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EAGAIN`, `EBADF` etc. are symbols for system error numbers, [defined in `errno.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/errno.h.html). They are compatible with `strerror` and related functions.

Note that [`write`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html) doesn’t return one of these values on error; on error, it returns -1, and sets `errno` appropriately.

Few functions return error numbers; amusingly enough, one of them is [`strerror_r`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strerror_r.html), which returns 0 on success, or `EINVAL` or `ERANGE` on failure.

Comment: This 1980 style 0 on success != 0 on failure +errno was never to my liking. It comes from a time, where multiple points of exit in a function were not considered a code smell. And in times of UNIX V, where there was no multi threading and global variables were also not a code smell. Even if errno is now in TLS, it is a relic of a barbaric past...